# Prime and Primary Ideals in Completion of a ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory

Let $(R,\mathfrak m)$ be a local noetherian ring and $\widehat{R}$  its $\mathfrak m$-adic completion.

1. If $\mathfrak q\in \operatorname{Spec}(\widehat{R})$ then can we find $\mathfrak p\in  \operatorname{Spec}(R)$ such that $\mathfrak q=\mathfrak p\widehat{R}$ ?
2. Is a primary ideal of  $\widehat{R}$   an extension of a primary ideal of  $R$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. This is false: take $R$ a local noetherian integral domain such that $\hat R$ is not an integral domain and $\mathfrak q$ a minimal ideal of $\hat R$. Since $R\to\hat R$ is (faithfully) flat $\mathfrak q$ is lying over $(0)$ and $\mathfrak q\neq(0)$.
2. Obviously, from 1., this is also false. However one can say something positive: there is a one-to-one correspondence between the set of $\mathfrak m$-primary ideals in $R$ and the set of $\hat{\mathfrak m}$-primary ideals in $\hat R$ given by $\mathfrak a\to\mathfrak a\hat R$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for editing and answering. I seriously need a good reference to study and undrestand completions of rings. It would be nice if you could recommend me a  book or lecture note that treats the subject using more examples.(I've read Matsumura, Enochs-Genda, McDonnald-Attiyah but don't have a clear grasp of this subject)

Comment: @Nemo Try *Topics in $\mathfrak m$-adic topologies* by S. Greco, P. Salmon.

Comment: @26857: How can I construct a ring "$R$ a local noetherian integral domain such that $\hat R$ is not an integral domain."

Comment: There are some (non-local) examples here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186547/can-the-completion-of-a-domain-be-a-non-domain