# Minimal prime ideals of $\hat R$ contract to minimal primes of $R$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory

> In what conditions from $P\in\operatorname{Min}\widehat R$ can we deduce that $P\cap R\in \operatorname{Min} R$ ?

Here $(R,\mathfrak m)$ is a commutative Noetherian local ring, $\widehat R$ its $\mathfrak m$-adic completion and  $\operatorname{Min} R$ the minimal primes of $R$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[As I've already told you](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/399284/prime-and-primary-ideals-in-completion-of-a-ring), the going-down theorem holds for flat $R$-algebras (see, for instance, Matsumura, *Commutative Ring Theory*, Theorem 9.5). Since $R\to\hat{R}$ is (faithfully) flat and $P$ a minimal prime in $\hat R$, then $\mathfrak p=P\cap R$ is also minimal. Otherwise let $\mathfrak q$ be a prime ideal of $R$ with $\mathfrak q\subset \mathfrak p$. Going-down theorem says that there exists a prime $Q$ of $\hat R$ with $Q\subset P$ such that $Q\cap R=\mathfrak q$ (obviously $Q\neq P$) and this contradicts the minimality of $P$.

Comment: :Thanks again. I knew that I've seen something about this somewhere but couldn't find it as much as I browsed the books!