# Completion w.r.t. regular maximal ideal

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra

**My question:** Let $R$ be an integral domain which is finitely generated as an algebra over a field or $\mathbb{Z}$. Is it true that the completion of $R$ w.r.t. a regular maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ (i.e. the localization $R_\mathfrak{m}$ is a regular local ring) is again an integral domain? (If yes, does this proof exist in the literature somewhere?)

According to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186547/can-the-completion-of-a-domain-be-a-non-domain), this is equivalent to the fact that there is a unique maximal ideal $\mathfrak{M}$ above $\mathfrak{m}$ in the integral closure of $R$ in its quotient field. But I do not know how to prove that in case of regular maximal $\mathfrak{m} \subseteq R$. But other approaches are, of course, welcome as well.

Comment: Isn't the completion of $R$ at $m$ the same as the completion of $R_m$ at $mR_m$?

Comment: @user26857: Indeed, I think so. But how does that help?

Comment: Its minimal number of generators does not change under completion as well as the dimension.

Comment: @Youngsu: Are you suggesting that the completion will be a regular local ring (and hence an integral domain) as well?

Comment: @Algebrus This must be a classical result; https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/07NU