# Is the completion of a regular integral domain at an ideal a domain?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $X$ be a regular integral affine scheme, with $X = \operatorname{Spec} R$. Let $I$ be an ideal of $R$. Is $\underleftarrow{\lim} R/I^n$ still a domain?

Note that in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186547/can-the-completion-of-a-domain-be-a-non-domain) the assumption about the regularity has been omitted, and the counterexamples in that post make use of the singularity.

Comment: When you say $X$ smooth, do you mean the canonical morphism $X\to\operatorname{Spec} \Bbb Z$ is smooth, or do you have another base in mind (maybe the spectrum of a field)?

Comment: Have you tried the case when $I=M_1M_2$ where $M_i$s are distinct maximal ideals?