# Showing two rings are not isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-isomorphism

Consider $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(y^2-x^3)$ and $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(y^2-x^3-x^2)$.
Someone told me that these two rings are not isomorphic, but I don't know how to prove.
Please help me.

Comment: Shortly I hope a commutative algebraist will come through and say that you can see it from the zero-set in the plane. When you graph the first, there is a cusp at $0$. In the second there is no cusp, but curve intersects itself there.  No doubt these distinguish the two.

Comment: To expand on rschwieb's comment, you can distinguish these two by looking at completions. If there is an isomorphism between the two, it carries maximal ideals to maximal ideals, which by the Nullstellensatz are all of the form $(x - a, y - b)$ for some $a,b\in\Bbb{C}.$ Then, to algebraically see the difference between the cusp and the node, compute the completions of $(\Bbb{C}[x,y]/(y^2 - x^3))_{(x - a,y - b)}$ and $(\Bbb{C}[x,y]/(y^2 - x^3 - x^2))_{(x,y)}$ at their maximal ideals.

Comment: [continued] At most points $(a,b),$ the former will look like $\Bbb{C}[\![y-b]\!],$ but at $(0,0)$ you'll get $\Bbb{C}[\![x,y]\!]/((y - x)(y + x)).$ For $(\Bbb{C}[x,y]/(y^2 - x^3 - x^2))_{(x,y)}$, I believe you should get something isomorphic to $\Bbb{C}[\![t]\!]/(t^2).$ Then you simply need to show $\Bbb{C}[\![t]\!]/(t^2)$ is not isomorphic to $\Bbb{C}[\![t]\!]$ or to $\Bbb{C}[\![x,y]\!]/((y - x)(y + x)).$

Comment: [continued] The geometric intuition here is that localizing and completing at $(x - a,y - b)$ is like zooming in at the point $(a,b)$ on the graph of the curve, and everywhere except $(0,0)$ the curve will look like a line, and at $(0,0)$ you'll either look like two lines intersecting at a point or a "double line."

Comment: @Stahl the completion of the local ring of the cusp is reduced, not isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[[t]]/(t^2)$, so you will need another argument (The other part is right.) (This follows from a theorem of Chevalley, see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytically_unramified_ring -- I don't know a proof for this particular ring.)

Comment: @hunter whoops! Hmm, well, the argument will still work as long as the completion isn't isomorphic to $\Bbb{C}[\![x,y]\!]/(y^2 - x^2)$ or $\Bbb{C}[\![t]\!].$ If it is isomorphic to $\Bbb{C}[\![t]\!],$ you could run the game in the other order, and show that the cuspidal cubic has no local ring isomorphic to $\Bbb{C}[\![x,y]\!]/(y^2 - x^2)$ (this will surely be true, though I haven't run the computations).

Comment: @Stahl I tried to bang out an argument below. (Incidentally, it also shows the local ring of the cusp is a domain so in particular reduced, if it's right -- I am very sleepy so it may be wrong!)

Comment: @hunter I'm also running empty (why I commented instead of answering), so I'll check out your argument tomorrow! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by Stahl in the comments, if these rings were isomorphic, then $\mathbb{C}[[x, y]] / (y^2 - x^3)$ and $\mathbb{C}[[x, y]]/(y^2 - x^3 - x^2)$ would be isomorphic.

But the former ring is an integral domain, and the latter is not.

Proof that $\mathbb{C}[[x, y]] / (y^2 - x^3)$ is an integral domain: map $\mathbb{C}[[x, y]] \to \mathbb{C}[[t]]$ by $x \mapsto t^2$ and $y \mapsto t^3$. Let's check that the kernel is exactly $(y^2 - x^3)$. Any power series
$$
f(x, y) = a_{00} + a_{10}x + a_{01}y + a_{20}x^2 + a_{11}xy + a_{02}y^2 + a_{30} x^3 + \ldots
$$
in the kernel of this map satisfies
$$
a_{00} + a_{10}t^2 + a_{01}t^3 + a_{20}t^4 + a_{11}t^5 + (a_{02} + a_{30})t^6 + \ldots = 0,
$$
so in particular all the coefficients below $a_{02}$ are zero, and for each $n$,
$$
\sum_{2i + 3j = n} a_{ij} = 0.
$$
We are reduced to showing that any polynomial of the form
$$
\sum_{2i + 3j = n} a_{ij}x^iy^j
$$
is divisible by $y^2 - x^3$ when the sum of its coefficients is zero. We can replace every copy of $y^2$ with $x^3$ in the polynomial to check this, so (depending on the parity of $n$) our expression is either $y \sum a_{ij} x^{(n-1)/2}$ or $\sum a_{ij} x^{n/2}$, which is obviously zero either way.

Proof that $\mathbb{C}[[x, y]]/(y^2 - x^3 - x^2)$ is not an integral domain: we have $x^3 + x^2 = x^2(1+x)$. Now $(1+x)$ is a square in $\mathbb{C}[[x, y]]$, using the Taylor expansion of the square root function, that is, there exists $z$ with $x^3 + x^2 = z^2x^2$. Then $(y+zx)(y-zx) = y^2 - x^3 - x^2 =  0$ in the quotient, but neither $y + zx$ nor $y - zx$ are (they are degree $1$ in $y$ and $zx$ doesn't have any $y$-terms).

(Technically this only proves there is no $\mathbb{C}$-algebra isomorphism; I am not sure if there is an exotic ring isomorphism that is non-linear on the $\mathbb{C}$ part, since you have a bunch of transcendental garbage in $\mathbb{C}$ to work with in that case.)

(EDIT: oh, it's fine. The first ring has the property that for any maximal ideal, the completion is a domain. The latter doesn't have this property. So they can't be isomorphic.)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/186549/121097