# Conditions such that the completion of a domain is still a domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, noetherian

In the question
[Can the completion of a domain be a non-domain?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186547/can-the-completion-of-a-domain-be-a-non-domain)
it is shown that the completion of an integral domain could be not anymore a domain. I was wondering if there are conditions that ensure the completion stays an integral domain. For example if we consider $R$ a noetherian integral domain and we have that the ideal $I$ is generated by a regular sequence is then $R^{\wedge}_I$ a domain? I could not find much in the literature about topic.

I do not have a deep background in algebra, so I could not think of any approach to tackle such problem. Any contribution is welcomed.

Comment: I somehow suspect that a good answer to this question will not be very elementary. The examples in the linked question refer to global irreducibility versus local... which (to my perception) is quite non-trivial to understand.

Comment: Since I did not find any answer to such question in the literature I also share your suspect, but still if someone has in mind even a partial result in this direction I would be glad to hear it.

Comment: The other answer in the post you linked did give some conditions (excellent, Noetherian, only one maximal lying over $\mathfrak m$ in the integral closure) that guarantee the completion is a domain. Are you looking for a different set of conditions?

Comment: Yes: what if we are localizing with respect an ideal which is not the maximal one?

Comment: One important result in this direction is Zariski's main theorem. It says that if $(A,M)$ is a local Noetherian domain and $A$ is integrally closed, then the completion (with respect to the maximal ideal $M$) is a domain.

Comment: @N.B. Localizing or taking completion?

Comment: Taking the completion, sorry for the mistake.

Comment: @Mohan could you please provide a reference for the statement you speak of? From what I know Zariski's main theorem admits several formulations, probably they are all equivalent or strictly related and the version you mention probably is one of the easiest. But as I said above my background in algebra is not very deep, a precise reference with the proof would help me a lot.

Comment: You can find it in Zariski Samuel book on algebra.